# Laravel search in pivot table with pagination

Tags: laravel, search, filter, eloquent, relationship

I need to search genre of demo.

Note: I have hidden other search for the shake of brevity.

## Background:

Tables:

1. Users [id, name, ...]
2. Demos [id, name, user_id]
3. Genres [id, name]
4. demo_genre (pivot table) [demo_id, genre_id]

## Code

```
$user = (new User)->newQuery();
$user->with(['demos' =>function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('genres', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('genre_id',[2,3,4]);
    });
}]);


$user->paginate();
```

**Note**: The above code works if there are search result has data. But returns empty demos array if the genres are not found in pivot table.

**Question**: How to remove the results that don't match supplied condition (ie: `$query->whereIn('genre_id',[2,3,4]);`). And display the demos which match the condition.

**Conditions:**

1. Show user with demos [results that have demos with genre_id in (2,3,4)]
2. Only show demo which has genre_id in (2,3,4)
3. Don't show the user if the domo's count is zero

Comment: If you closely look into it $query->whereIn('genre_id',[2,3,4]); acts as a subquery to fetch demos. What I see here you have to use leftJoin and add where clause instead of using eloquent relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `only the users who has demos which has particular genres`

```
$user->whereHas('demos', function($demoQuery) {
    $demoQuery->whereHas('genres', function ($genreQuery) {
        $genreQuery->whereIn('id',[2,3,4]);
    });
})
->with([
    'demos' => function($demoQuery) {
        $demoQuery->whereHas('genres', function ($genreQuery) {
            $genreQuery->whereIn('id',[2,3,4]);
        });
])
->get();
```

`where()` is to filter, `with()` is to eager load demos.

Comment: your answer solved the problem, but introduced another one, which I had forgot to mention. I need to display demos that match the condition.

Comment: @AmritShrestha Just chain `->with('demos')` at the end.

Comment: I think `->with(['demos' => function($demoQuery) {
    $demoQuery->whereHas('genres', function ($genreQuery) {
        $genreQuery->whereIn('id',[2,3,4]);
    });
}]);`

Comment: @TharakaDilshan: your query returns blank demo. I need the record to be removed if demo count is zero.

Comment: no the point is you need to write both. `->whereHas()->with()` I cant write it in this comment I will edit the answer

Comment: I did the same thing as your edited answer and was testing. And it seems to be working. Is there a better way to this? This has the same query repeated twice.

Comment: No, actually its complicated to explain executing queries here. But two queries  are always executing weather they are different or the same, when you eager load a relationship `with()`. One query to fetch original table, another query to fetch relationship.